# Which summation should be chosen for a divergent series arising from the expression of relative mass in order to always preserve the same mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mathematical-physics, renormalization, mathematics

In all physical theories, the appearance of infinity is generally regarded as a sign that the theory is either incorrect or being applied outside its applicable domain, necessitating the search for another theory to make sense of this infinity.

Even in the theory of relativity, when infinity appears in the study of a black hole, it does not necessarily mean that a black hole is impossible to exist, but rather that we have reached the limits of applicability of the theory of relativity and need to seek another theory that provides a broader framework to study black holes.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)

So, why is it accepted that when $c = v$  and the infinity of mass or energy appears, it is impossible to reach the speed of light, even though the theory of relativity is reaching beyond its applicable domain with the emergence of this infinity of mass and energy?

So I try to make sense of this infinity that has no physical meaning:

Consider the function $M(v) = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$, where $v \in ]-c;c[$ and $m0\in \mathbb{R}^{*+}$ , and $c=3.10^8$.

Let $(U_n)$ be a sequence with general term $U_n = M(c-1/(n+2))-M(c-1/(n+1))$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let the series with general term $S_n$ be defined as $S_n = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots+U_n$.

Let $S$ be the sum of the series defined as $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots$.

With the Cesàro summation method, the series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots=+\infty$ diverges to infinity, so it does not converge in the sense of Cesàro, just like the series $1+2+3+\dots=+\infty$.

For more details, please refer to this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

For the divergent series $1+2+3+\dots$, it can be summed using the zeta regularization summation method to converge to $-1/12$.

For more details, please refer to this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Questions:

Is there a summation method where the divergent series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots$ converges to a finite value?

Does this summation method, where the divergent series converges to a value of $m_0$, have any physical significance?

Could it explain the high-speed movement at the speed of light of certain UFOs confirmed by NASA?

Detail:

For your information, the divergence at v=c of the function M(v) can be represented as:

For $v=c$, we have $M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)$.

I let $x+2=1/(c-v)$, so $v=c-1/(x+2)$ Therefore:

$M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)=\lim_{{x \to +\infty}}M(c-1/(x+2))$.

So we have:

$M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)=\lim_{{x \to +\infty}}M(c-1/(x+2))=\lim_{{n\to +\infty}}M(c-1/(n+2))$.

I let $S_n=M(c-1/(n+2))$ so $U_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ so $S_n = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots+U_n$
so  $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots=+\infty$.

so  $M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)=S$

Comment: You already asked this twice before.

Comment: And you asked me to edit the question because it wasn't well understood, and I did it

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Expansions-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486603180

Comment: Why would you try "removing an infinity" when this is a natural and consistent result of relativity? You don't want to remove something that is completely consistent with what we expect. You do this when the infinity is inconsistent, and cannot be right, so the entire premise of this question is wrong.

Comment: If we find R(S), we can conduct an experiment to verify if c = v. Physics is not just a theoretical science but also an experimental science. This hypothesis and experiment are also based on the equation of relativity, so they are mathematically supported , I contest the fact that relativity uses a non-physical notion, infinity, to conclude the impossibility of traveling at the speed of light, And that's a plausible argument...

Comment: *And you asked me to edit the question because it wasn't well understood, and I did it* No, you didn’t. Edit means using the Edit feature. It doesn’t  mean deleting and reposting.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood that either I edit the question or I make a new one. I don't speak English, I'm just using a translator, And the question I no longer see it delete.

Comment: Ok I edit tag Special relativity and renormalization

Comment: You seem to have formulated this question *very* opaquely in my opinion. Wouldn't it be simpler to just ask about regularizing the divergent series $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{35}{128}+\dots$ that comes from setting $\beta=1$ in the Taylor expansion of the Lorentz factor $(1-\beta^2)^{-1/2}$? I think one *can* apply Ramanujan summation to it, but I *don't* think that this has any physical significance whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, why not, but what I'm mainly looking for is that if we find such a finite summation that gives m0, we could conceive a feasible experiment to test if v = c. For example, if a UFO is detected by NASA and becomes immobile before reaching the speed of light with the same mass, emitting pulses that disrupt the instruments, I think this could be due to this summation R that renders the object immobile before reaching the speed of light.Here are examples to make such summation of divergent sequence ...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should avoid using ChatGPT as a reference about math/phys questions, a lot of the time it is incorrect or gives you answers unrelated to what you ask him.

Said that, you can't renormalize that serie or regularise it. It has no finite value. This is not how regularisation works at all.

Renormalization is the procedure which is needed to relate the parameters in the theory with the parameters you measure in a lab. You can also use it to express the change in your parameters as the reference scale of the theory changes. It has absolutely nothing to do with making infinitesimal finite for the sake of them being finite. So no, no finite value for that expression.

The function $M(v)$ you have is to be interpreted as the inertial resistance of your object.

The physical meaning of $M(c) = \infty$ is that an object with mass will have an infinite inertial resistance at $v=c$. This infinity means that to accelerate a massive object from $v<c$ to $v=c$ requires an infinite amount of energy. There is no renormalization to cure that.

Comment: And if I'm looking for a regularization that yields Sn= m₀?

Comment: In all physical theories, the appearance of infinity is generally regarded as a sign that the theory is either incorrect or being applied outside its applicable domain, necessitating the search for another theory to make sense of this infinity. Even in the theory of relativity, when infinity appears in the study of a black hole, it does not necessarily mean that a black hole is impossible to exist, but rather that we have reached the limits of applicability of the theory of relativity and need to seek another theory that provides a broader framework to study black holes.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)  So, why is it accepted that when c = v and the infinity of mass or energy appears, it is impossible to reach the speed of light, even though the theory of relativity is reaching beyond its applicable domain with the emergence of this infinity of mass and energy?

Comment: The fact that you don't know what are you talking about and keep posting chatGPT text as an answer is mildly offensive and a wast of users time. ChatGPT is not a physics textbook and you can't use it to study instead of a proper textbook. The infinity in the energy is not an infinity of the theory, it means that $v=c$ cannot be reached by a classical massive object. It has nothing to do with the domain of applicability of a theory

Comment: Only one paragraph about regularization is taken from ChatGPT.
I gave the source wikipedia you can watch it

Comment: I studied regularisation in 3 different courses, I know what you are talking about. I am telling you that regularisation has nothing to do with this being infinity. Just like the infinite extension of the universe has nothing to do with regularisation because you get $Vol = \infty$

Comment: I know what the purpose is.It is a discrepancy that can be treated like the others and put a condition to do it regularization.  It is enough to make a good condition to normalize this divergence and find a regularization and the condition is to keep the same mass m0 ,We have an equivalent infinity of Sn to find m0 and find the best regularization..

Comment: I edited the question, is it clearer?

Comment: Sigh. The correct answer to OP is that the infinity that appears when $v=c$ is a correct physical prediction of the Special Theory of Relativity and is routinely verified by physics experiments. If you find a way to get rid of this infinity, then your hypothetical theory is just physically wrong. And it is not necessary to be working in units where the infinity appears at $v=c$. We can use rapidity $\chi$, where the infinity appears at $\chi=\infty$, if that is what is desired. It is just not always convenient to use rapdity where velocity is more natural to use.

Comment: If we find R(S), we can conduct an experiment to verify if c = v. Physics is not just a theoretical science but also an experimental science. This hypothesis and experiment are also based on the equation of relativity, so they are mathematically supported. However, I contest the fact that relativity uses a non-physical notion, infinity, to conclude the impossibility of traveling at the speed of light...

Comment: We already have experimental confirmation that the energy increases as predicted by SR as $v\to c$. This means that any future theory that wishes to be accepted as correct, must also have this growth. Why should a correct physical theory be concerned by your insistence to contest it?

Comment: It does not question relativity for v<c but in the case where v=c, clearly here is my hypothesis there is a series of energy impulses to apply an object to have v=c and always the same mass m0.
This series of impulses is R(S)=m0.
By applying R(S) the object will be moved then directly go to the speed of light.NASA has already observed a UFO doing this first it becomes motionless then it launches a series of impulses which make the measuring instruments bug then it disappears at the speed of light are doubt with R (S)